# Как на джанго открыть сайт для локальной сети?

Tags: python, django

Мне нужно открыть сайт джанго на который можно будет зайти только из локальной сети wifi. Как это можно сделать без хостинга? Мне нужно чтобы сайт находился на пк и на него можно было зайти с другого устройства в локальной сети.

Comment: Запустить django на пк и на другом устройстве вводить соответствующие ip-адрес и порт

Comment: 127.1 по умолчанию)

Answer (score 1):

Для домашнего использования и тестов

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Будет принимать подключения с локальной сети в том числе. Для смены порта на 80 лучше использовать nginx с proxypass

Для продакшена смотрите установку с gunicorn